# What is the difference between it.first and it->first?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap

```
for(auto it = M.begin(); it!=M.end();it++)
    {
        cout<<it->first<<" "<<it->second<<"\n";  
    }
```

The above code works absolutely fine
But,

```
    for(auto it : M)
    {
        if(it->second == 1) return it->first;
    }
```

This gives me an error.
 Why do I have to use `it.second` and `it.first` instead of `it->second` and `it->first`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the first loop, you use ***iterators*** to iterate over the container `M`. Iterators emulate pointers, and have to be dereferenced to give the value the iterator is "pointing" at. In fact, for that loop, `it->first` is really the same as `(*it).first`.

In the second loop, you loop over the ***values*** in the container `M`. The loop itself uses iterators internally and dereferences them for you. [This reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) about "range-based `for` loops" might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you use `.` operator to access members of objects and `it->first` simply means `(*it).first`. So `it` is a pointer pointing to your variable which has a member `first`, so to access `first`, you just dereference the pointer then use `.` to access the member. 
Now if `it` was your variable instead of a pointer to the variable, then you could simply access its member `first` via `it.first`.